# Return Latest Row DateTime For All Tables in a SQL Server Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, ssms-2016

I have a database `[database1]` that has thousands of tables within it. Each Table has a Row Insert Update Date/Time Column `[EventDateTime]` in them, not necessarily as a primary key.

I was hoping to create a query that creates a temporary table (or a print view) with two columns in it; `[TableName]` & `[LatestEventDateTime]`.

I am thinking I might be able to use `sp_MSforeachtable` to retrieve the data, but I am not sure how to call the `max [EventDateTime]` for each table.

These would be a great validation query to confirm every table is being updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it like that:

```
USE tempdb

IF OBJECT_ID(N'#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp (
    TableName nvarchar(max),
    MaxEventDateTime datetime
)

USE YourDatabaseName

INSERT INTO #temp
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'SELECT ''?'', MAX([EventDateTime]) FROM ?'

SELECT *
FROM #temp
```

Note: `sp_MSforeachtable` is undocumented stored procedure and I don't recommend to use it on vital production processes.

I suggest you dynamic SQL solution:

```
USE tempdb

IF OBJECT_ID(N'#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp (
    TableName nvarchar(max),
    MaxEventDateTime INT
)

USE YourDatabaseName

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @sql = (
    SELECT 'INSERT INTO #temp SELECT '''+[name]+''', MAX([EventDateTime]) FROM '+QUOTENAME([name])+';'+CHAR(10)
    FROM sys.tables 
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

--PRINT @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

`PRINT @sql` will bring you query like this:

```
USE [Test] INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 'TABLE_A', COUNT(*) FROM [TABLE_A];
USE [Test] INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 'TABLE_B', COUNT(*) FROM [TABLE_B];
USE [Test] INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 'TestXml', COUNT(*) FROM [TestXml];
USE [Test] INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 'Clients', COUNT(*) FROM [Clients];
```

I advice you to use dynamic SQL solution.

Comment: I'm sure the first one works great on smaller databases but it seems to take for ever on the  one I was working with.

Comment: The second one seems to cut out on my after 13.5 lines which is kinda silly given the size of nvarchar(max).  The only thing I am concerned about is wether or not this concept requires performing an entire database scan.  Which in my case would make it completely useless.

Comment: @DataMan31 You get 13,5 lines because of `PRINT`, try to select a part between `select @sql(<here to select>)` and run it. You will see all the lines are on their places.